# How should I interpret numbers 3 and 4 on the footprint schematic?

Tags: symbol, footprint

I am creating a foot print for this [PoE magjack](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Bel%20Fuse%20PDFs/0826-1L1T-57-F.pdf) and was wondering how to correctly interpret the symbols for 3 and 4 on page 5. From the schematic, these pins get wired but I am confused as to why they are not holes. Thanks

Comment: Look at the 'schematic' diagram on page 1 - there are no pins 3 & 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schematic for the connector has RJ45 pins (1-8) on the right, and footprint pins (1-2, 5-15) are on the left.

[image]

Comment: Okay. Second question, Will I have to wire the capacitors and resistors or are these integrated in the connector itself?

Comment: @circuit_noob533 They are *inside* the connector. You will need to wire up all connections on the outside of the "footprint", but that's pretty much it.

Comment: Thanks. I notice that there are two Vc pairs from the connector. Does this mean I effectively have two power lines to work with? Or do these need to be joined through a junction to create one +/- pair. Side note: My application requires me to power Rpi0 and a VoIP phone.

Comment: @circuit_noob533 Applications that I've seen take the DC lines and pass them into a 4-input bridge rectifier before adding on the PoE negotiating circuits and isolated DC-DC converter

Answer (score 1):

Pins 3 & 4 are not actual pins, they are placeholders, skipping these pins makes it easier to define the mechanical dimensions.